# With BCM_SETIMAGELIST who destroys the HIMAGELIST?

Tags: winapi, controls, windows-controls

I was looking at `BCM_SETIMAGELIST` but it's not clear who is supposed to destroy the `HIMAGELIST`?  If the one who created it, could `WM_NCDESTROY` be used to simple `BCM_GETIMAGELIST` and destroy it or should you get it first then set it to nothing, like -1, then destroy it?

TIA!!

Comment: It's not conclusive, but it's standard for Microsoft documentation to tell you if/when an API assumes ownership of a resource. If it's not mentioned at all then I would say it's safe to assume that you retain ownership of the image list.